# Making objects easier and cleaner

Tags: java, object, if-statement

Every time I want to make a new dog I'll have to add more if statements which will make the code more unreadable. How would I make this code cleaner and in the future how would I make more dogs easier without adding more if?

```
public class Animals {
    String userName;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Dog oscar = new Dog("Oscar", "German Shepherd", "No one", 2);
    Dog sheeba = new Dog("Sheeba", "BullDog", "No one", 4);

    public void Username() {
        System.out.println("Your Name?");
        userName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello " + userName);
    }

    public void myAnimal () {
        System.out.println("Please Choose a Dog | Oscar | Sheeba ");
        String chooseDog = scanner.nextLine();
        if (chooseDog.equals("Oscar")) {
            oscar.info();
            System.out.println("Adopt Oscar? | Yes | No");

            String adoptOscar = scanner.nextLine();
            if (adoptOscar.equals("Yes")) {
                oscar.owner = userName;

                System.out.println("Change Oscar's name? | Yes | No");
                String changeOscar = scanner.nextLine();
                if (changeOscar.equals("Yes")) {
                    System.out.println("New Name");
                    String newOscar = scanner.nextLine();
                    oscar.name = newOscar;
                } else if (changeOscar.equals("No")) {
                    oscar.info();
                }
                myAnimal();
            } else if (adoptOscar.equals("No")) {
                myAnimal();
            }
        } else if(chooseDog.equals("Sheeba")){
            sheeba.info();
            System.out.println("Adopt Sheeba? | Yes | No");

            String adoptSheeba = scanner.nextLine();
            if (adoptSheeba.equals("Yes")) {
                sheeba.owner = userName;
                System.out.println("Change Sheeba's name? | Yes | No");
                String changeSheeba = scanner.nextLine();
                if (changeSheeba.equals("Yes")) {
                    System.out.println("New Name");
                    String newSheeba = scanner.nextLine();
                    sheeba.name = newSheeba;
                } else if (changeSheeba.equals("No")) {
                    sheeba.info();
                }
                myAnimal();
            } else if (adoptSheeba.equals("No")) {
                myAnimal();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could indent your code properly first, it would be easier to read ;)

Comment: You modularize stuff and receive input parameters ;)

Comment: You write a small function for every repetitive task such as ```getUserInput``` or ```makeNew``` or ```rename```. That's procedural programming. To get to OOP, you then make ```class Dog``` and attach all those methods to the class. Then  you can make, say ```class Cat``` with its own ```makeNew``` and ```rename``` functions, but you can just reuse ```getUserInput``` with no problems.

Comment: This question may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @dnault it would be, if OP provided a description of what the purpose of the code is, and made the title summarize that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you want to factor what is common, so you don't end up repeating yourself in the code. Here the process is the same for each dog, so really waht you want is a way to handle all the dogs the same way.

What you can do:

- Create a list of `Dog` in your class and add your dogs to it.
- When you ask the user to choose one, just read the names in your list to print them out.
- When the User chooses a dog name, find the dog back from your list and deal with that dog.
- If the user changes the name of a dog, then the dof is updated on the list and next time you print the list, it will have the new name.

Ideally you have a separate method that deal with **any** dog. I called it `dealWithDog` in the below example.

(I avoided using Stream and Optional to keep the code straightforward with loops)

```
public class Animals {
    private String userName;
    private Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    // This list will hold all your dogs
    private List<Dog> dogs;

    public Animals() {
        // Add the dogs to the list on the class constructor
        dogs = new ArrayList<>();
        dogs.add(new Dog("Oscar", "German Shepherd", "No one", 2));
        dogs.add(new Dog("Sheeba", "BullDog", "No one", 4));
    }

    public void myAnimal () {
        // Display dog names (this could be in a separate method)
        System.out.println("Please Choose a Dog:");
        for(Dog dog : dogs) {
            System.out.println(dog.getName());
        }

        // Find the chosen dog (this could be in a separate method)
        String chooseDog = scanner.nextLine();
        for(Dog dog : dogs) {
            if(dog.getName().equals(chooseDog)) {
                // Deal with the chosen dog
                dealWithDog(dog);
            }
        }

        // Do it all over again
        myAnimal();
    }

    private void dealWithDog(Dog dog) {
        System.out.println(dog.getInfo());
        System.out.println("Adopt "+dog.getName()+"? | Yes | No");

        String adoptDog = scanner.nextLine();
        if (adoptDog.equals("Yes")) {
            dog.setOwner(userName);

            System.out.println("Change "+dog.getName()+"'s name? | Yes | No");
            String changeName = scanner.nextLine();
            if (changeName.equals("Yes")) {
                System.out.println("New Name");
                String newName = scanner.nextLine();
                dog.setName(newName);
            } else if (changeName.equals("No")) {
                System.out.println(dog.getInfo());
            }
        }
    }

    public void username() {
        System.out.println("Your Name?");
        userName = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Hello " + userName);
    }
}
```

Regarding the `Dog` class, make your fields private and only expose the ones you need to expose via getters and setters. Should look something like this:

```
class Dog {
    private String info;
    private String name;
    private String owner;
    private int age;

    public Dog(String name, String info, String owner, int age) {
        this.info = info;
        this.name = name;
        this.owner = owner;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // GETTERS/ SETTERS
}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you. You literally just did my homework. I really didn't familiarized myself with getters and setters since all of them were about ints. But thanks dude. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Make sure you understand everything. Also it would be nice to not have that `username()` method in your `Animal` class because it is not related. Better pass the username as a parameter to the `myAnimal()` method (ie `myAnimal(String username)` ). A lot of improvements can still be done.

Comment: Ok. But another thing. I added another method where you could choose again if you like. And if you agree on changing the dogs name to something like "Barbecue" in that choose again method it will print out the new name instead of the old one. Wow!! And yes i think i understand everything. Most of it just relied on the setter and gettrs which i didn't do and rn I'm learning more about the arraylist thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can create another class:

```
class Dogs{
  private List<Dog> dogs;

  public Dogs(List<Dog> dogs){
    this.dogs = dogs;
  }
  //getter, setter
}
```

After this, you can iterate the list with

```
for (Dogs dog:animals.getDogs()){
   if(readerDog.equals(dog.getName())){
      //do wathever you want here.
    }
}
```

Tip: you can modularize your class animals to store only the element username, and create another class to make the another stuffs.

Tip: Create another classe with the name user, and receive the username and list of animals of that guy.

Comment: So a lot of you guys suggested that i should make more classes. Well I'm scared to do that since i guy i was having a conversation on reddit slightly scolded me for making unneccessary classes. Before the Username and myAnimal was separated but after what the guy said i merged them together. This was a good idea since at the time i didn't know how to set the dog's owner to the name the user inputed. But i just realized i could just make a class that has all the methods. that would save me time.

Comment: every different aspect of your program!